# SKMaps eglChooseConfig IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, skmaps

I have searched and searched this one and cannot seem to solve. Im running OSX 10.9 on an iMac with a ATI RADEON 4670 and and trying to get Skobbler Scouts maps to run on an Android emulator. All I keep getting is the dreaded eglChooseConfig() returning false using the inbuilt Android Emulator with all the prescribed settings set by Skobbler (gpu on API level etc etc). Is this a hardware incompatibility issue or is the Emulator just not implemented with the attribute settings set by Skobbler? Alternatively does anyone know of a working emulator for this SDK?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Andy

Comment: It's recommended to use a real device when testing, as emulators are not reliable when dealing with OpenGL rendering

Comment: Thanks, was thinking that myself but the problem where Android is concerned is the vast array of layout sizes, densities and qualifiers as opposed to iOS. This makes emulation more important on Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a working configuration at http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec031 (I've tested with device = Nexus 5 and API level 20).

Unfortunately, due to the fact that the SDK relies heavily on OpenGL most emulators will exhibit weird behaviours - leaving only real devices as good testing options (the emulator's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) also states that OpenGL support is "tricky": *"OpenGL® Graphics - Emulation of OpenGL ES graphics may not perform at the same level as an actual device"*)